# Getting value on the literal1.text in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, tags

I would like to ask if how can I get the value inside the `<span>` tag in literal1.text.

This is my code.

```
Literal1.Text = Literal1.Text & "<div class='chip' style='padding:8px;display:inline-block;border-radius: 25px;background:white;color:black;'><span>" & TextBox3.Text & "<i class='close fa fa-times'></i></span></div> &nbsp;"
```

I using it a tagbox in my project.

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZw2j.png)

Or if you have any suggestions on how can I create a tagbox in asp.net webforms that I can easily retrieve the data and save it in the database. I would really need and will appreciate the help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a formview around the Textbox to insert the Tags into the database and then retrieve it and insert with a Repeater.

Add your query into the SqlDataSource and edit the Bind to the name of your column name.

Please note I haven't tested it but to my knowledge, it should work.

```
 <asp:FormView runat="server" id="FormView1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="TextBox1" Text='<%# Bind("TagName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button runat="server" id="InsertButton" CommandArgument="Insert"></asp:Button>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
            
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" id="Repeater1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class='chip' style='padding:8px;display:inline-block;border-radius: 25px;background:white;color:black;'>
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("TagName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        
        <!-- Add here your database querys for insert and select -->
        <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" id="SqlDataSource1"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```